# Pandas: Find rows where a particular column is not NA but all other columns are

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which contains a lot of NA values. I want to write a query which returns rows where a particular column is not NA but **all other** columns are NA.

I can get a Dataframe where all the column values are not NA easily enough:

```
df[df.interesting_column.notna()]
```

However, I cant figure out how to then say "from that DataFrame return only rows were every column that is not 'interesting_column' is NA". I can't use `.dropna` as all rows and columns will contain at least one NA value.

I realise this is probably embarrassingly simple. I have tried lots of `.loc` variations, join/merges in various configurations and I am not getting anywhere.

Any pointers before I just do a for loop over this thing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use a conjunction of the conditions:

```
df[df.interesting_column.notna() & (df.isnull().sum(axis=1) == len(df.columns) - 1)]
```

- `df.interesting_column.notna()` checks the column is non-null.
- `df.isnull().sum(axis=1) == len(df.columns) - 1` checks that the number of nulls in the row is the number of columns minus 1

Both conditions together mean that the entry in the column is the only one that is non-null.

Comment: Given the complexity of the filter logic, I would probably generate a `rows` mask, like @liliscent did in their post to improve readability.  In this case it would look something like `interesting_data_provided = df.interesting_column.notna()`, and then `other_data_not_provided = df.isnull().sum(axis=1) == len(df.columns) - 1`, and finally `df[interesting_data_provided & other_data_not_provided]`

Answer (score 2):

The `&` operator lets you row-by-row "and" together two boolean columns.  Right now, you are using `df.interesting_column.notna()` to give you a column of `TRUE` or `FALSE` values.  You could repeat this for all columns, using `notna()` or `isna()` as desired, and use the `&` operator to combine the results.

For example, if you have columns `a`, `b`, and `c`, and you want to find rows where the value in columns `a` is not `NaN` and the values in the other columns are `NaN`, then do the following:

```
df[df.a.notna() & df.b.isna() & df.c.isna()]
```

This is clear and simple when you have a small number of columns that you know about ahead of time.  But, if you have many columns, or if you don't know the column names, you would want a solution that loops over all columns and checks `notna()` for the `interesting_column` and `isna()` for the other columns.  The solution by @AmiTavory is a clever way to achieve this.  But, if you didn't know about that solution, here is a simpler approach.

```
for colName in df.columns:
    if colName == "interesting_column":
        df = df[ df[colName].notna() ]
    else:
        df = df[ df[colName].isna() ]
```

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is only reasonable for a small number of columns.  If you have a large number of columns, then your solution would be cleaner.

Comment: However, I like your detailed explanation of the parts.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I did think about doing it this way but unfortunately I don't know before hand what all the column names will be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
rows = df.drop('interesting_column', axis=1).isna().all(1) & df['interesting_column'].notna()
```

Example (suppose `c` is the interesting column):

```
In [99]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, np.nan, 2], 'b': [1, np.nan, 3], 'c':[4, 5, np.nan]})

In [100]: df
Out[100]: 
     a    b    c
0  1.0  1.0  4.0
1  NaN  NaN  5.0
2  2.0  3.0  NaN

In [101]: rows = df.drop('c', axis=1).isna().all(1) & df.c.notna()

In [102]: rows
Out[102]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

In [103]: df[rows]
Out[103]: 
    a   b    c
1 NaN NaN  5.0
```

Comment: This is just missing the final step where you select the rows from `df`, by doing `df[rows]`.

Comment: @TimJohns I interpret `rows` as that mask. But added in case others interpret it differently.